# Using IDLE to display script output like in Shell

Tags: python, python-idle

I hope this makes sense. When using the IDLE python shell and typing the commands one by one, there is an output or response to most lines of code typed.

When writing a script and then running that script in IDLE I don't get to see the same output in the shell, is there a way of enabling it, or a line of code to add to my script so it displays?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A feature of both standard interactive mode and the IDLE Shell (and presumably of other Python IDEs) is that the value of expressions entered in response to the `>>>`  or other interactive prompt is echoed on a line below.

When running a script, the value of an expression statement is not printed. This is because such expressions are often included in files for their side effects, and because output may not be wanted. One must explicitly `print()` or `sys.stdout.write()` to see the result .  So

```
>>> 2+3
5
```

must be written, for instance, as `print(2+3)` in a program executed all at once, whether from any editor or from a command line.  (In other words, this question is not really IDLE specific, although it is a common one from beginners, who often use IDLE.)

If this is not your problem, we need much more information to help.

Comment: Yes thanks Terry, that is exactly what I am asking. So if I understand you correctly there is no module I can use to echo line by line like in the shell, I have to explicitly use print() for each desired output?

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing one can put in the code file itself. *IF* code has a blank line after every compound statement, then I believe one could paste it into the standard REPL and have each statement executed with echoing of expressions.  Pasting multiple statements into IDLE Shell currently does not work.